# Syntax for using RELATED() function under IF Condition in POWER BI

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I have two tables:
table 1:

```
Product        LOB
BVPN           NS
SD-WAN         IS
QUICK START    NS
BVPN SMALL     OSBU
```

Table 2:

```
Product        LOB
BVPN           NS
SD-WAN         IS
QUICK START    NS
BVPN SMALL     NS
```

I want to create a custom column that will change the value "OSBU" in LOB column of table1 to NS based on the value in LOB column of table2 and keep other values the same. I used the following code but it's not giving me the desired output. Can anyone tell what is wrong?

```
Column =
IF (
    'table1'[LOB] = "OSBU",
    RELATED ( 'table2'[LOB] ),
    'table1'[GOLD_BILLING_PROFILE.Product/Service]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RELATED` function works between tables with a relationship established only. You would have to create a relationship between Table1 and Table2 based on Product and hopefully it is a one to one mapping. The following link should give you the basic details on creating and managing a relationship:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships

Hope this helps.

Edit:

I don't know why you are using a different variable for the FALSE Condition. Ideally it should be something like:

```
Column =
IF (
    'table1'[LOB] = "OSBU",
    RELATED ( 'table2'[LOB] ),
    'table1'[LOB]
)
```

Comment: I have created the mapping between these two tables. But the formula is changing the value where there is OSBU but the second part of the formula is not working. For rest of the values  (apart from OSBU), Its taking blank. I want the output in new column as             
```                                                                                                                                  LOB
NS
IS
NS
NS                                                                                                                                   ```

Comment: You are using a different column for the FALSE condition. I have added an edit, replacing the field with the LOB field. Hopefully that works.

Comment: Yes it worked. I was making this mistake. Sorry could not thank you earlier.